# Use in terraform azurerm_app_service.outbound_ip_addresses in azurerm_app_service.ip_restriction

Tags: azure, terraform

I have two azurerm_app_service. The first

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "first" {
  name = "${local.webAppFirstCloudName}"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"

  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.id}"
  ...
```

the above web app is reachable over the internet with a public ip.

The second is as well reachable over the internet with a public ip. But here I would like to set the ip address of the first webapp. So the second one is only reachable fort the first webapp.

Here is the description:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "second" {
  name = "${local.webAppSecondCloudName}"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"

  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.id}"

  tags = {
    ApplicationName = "${var.applicationName}"
    BU-CostCenter = "${var.buCostCenter}"
    CostCenter = "${var.costCenter}"
    ProjectNumber = "${var.projectNumber}"
    Requester = "${var.requester}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Owner = "${var.owner}"
  }

  site_config {
    scm_type = "LocalGit"
    linux_fx_version = "JAVA|8-jre8"

    ip_restriction = "${split(",", azurerm_app_service.webAppLsgCloud.outbound_ip_addresses)}"

  }

  app_settings = {
    JAVA_OPTS = "-Xmx2G -Dspring.profiles.active=${var.stage} -Djava.net.preferIPOv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=80 -Dazure.cosmosdb.key=${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db.primary_master_key} -Dazure.cosmosdb.uri=${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db.endpoint} -Dazure.storage.account-name=${azurerm_storage_account.storage.name} -Dazure.storage.account-key=${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_access_key}"
    WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS = "7"
  }
}
```

after enter

```
PS C:\workspaces\intellij\terraform> terraform plan -var-file="cloud.dev.tfvars" -out=execution-plan
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...

Error: azurerm_app_service.second: site_config.0.ip_restriction: should be a list
```

Anyone an idea how to transfer the list to a proper restriction format?

Comment: Wrap the value in `[]`. So something like `ip_restriction = ["${split(",", azurerm_app_service.webAppLsgCloud.outbound_ip_addresses)}"]`

Comment: I got the message `Error: azurerm_app_service.second: "site_config.0.ip_restriction.0.ip_address": required field is not set`. The structure of ip restrictions should be something like `[  { ip_address  = "185.46.212.0" subnet_mask = "255.255.254.0" },  { ip_address  = "40.67.217.201" subnet_mask = "255.255.255.255" }]` OR `[  { ip_address  = "185.46.212.0/32" },  { ip_address  = "40.67.217.201/32"}]`

Comment: Try to add enough IP filter sections to allow for enough items to be added to the whitelistedIPs list, Have a look at https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1518#issuecomment-403527219

Comment: @NancyXiong but how can I be sure how many outbound IP addresses I will have? In Java I would just make a loop, but in terraform I am clueless..

Answer (score 2):

ip_restriction is a subblock in it's own right, see https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html#ip_restriction

to use it correctly in terraform you would have something like

```
site_config {
  scm_type = "LocalGit"
  linux_fx_version = "JAVA|8-jre8"
   ip_restriction {
    ip_address  = azurerm_app_service.webAppLsgCloud.outbound_ip_addresses
  }
}
```

However, since webAppLsgCloud.outbound_ip_addresses is a list of addresses have either to use a set of blocks or as of terraform v0.12.0 use a `dynamic` block, something like:

```
site_config {
  scm_type = "LocalGit"
  linux_fx_version = "JAVA|8-jre8"

  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
    for_each = azurerm_app_service.webAppLsgCloud.outbound_ip_addresses
      content {
        ip_address  = cidrhost(ip_restriction.value,0)
        subnet_mask = cidrmask(ip_restriction.value)
      }
  }
}
```